# Efficiently converting numpy array to matrix

Tags: python, numpy, scikit-learn

I have data in the following format:

```
['FACTOR_1','FACTOR_2",'VALUE"]
['A'       ,'A'       ,2.0    ]
['A'       ,'B'       ,3.0    ]
['A'       ,'C'       ,2.2    ]
['A'       ,'D'       ,2.6    ]
['B'       ,'A'       ,2.6    ]
['B'       ,'B'       ,1.0    ]
['B'       ,'C'       ,6.0    ]
['B'       ,'D'       ,7.7    ]
['C'       ,'A'       ,2.1    ]
....
['D'       ,'D'       ,2.6    ]
```

It is in a data frame but I've been converting to a numpy array anyway.

I'd like to convert it into a matrix of the two factors.

I've coded it myself but the way I am currently doing it is **very** slow and inefficient, I have a nested loop and am searching for indices of the factors:

```
    no_of_factors = np.size(np.unique(cov_data['FACTOR_1']))
    factors = np.unique(cov_data['FACTOR_1'])

    cov_matrix = np.zeros((no_of_factors, no_of_factors))

    i = 0
    for factor_1 in factors:
        factor_indices = np.where(cov_data['FACTOR_1'] == factor_1)[0].tolist()
        j = 0
        for factor_2 in factors:
            factor_2_index = np.where(cov_data['FACTOR_2'][factor_indices] == factor_2)[0].tolist()
            if np.size(factor_2_index) > 1:
                self.log.error("Found duplicate factor")
            elif np.size(factor_2_index) == 0:
                var = 0
            else:
                factor_2_index = factor_2_index[0]
                var = cov_data['VALUE'][factor_2_index]
            cov_matrix[i][j] = var
            j += 1
        i += 1
```

Annoyingly the data also isn't perfect and there aren't values for every factor, for example factor C might only have a value for A and B and D might be missing hence the check and setting to 0.

Comment: You should show the intended result; that makes it easier to understand and test. In fact the `cov_data` object isn't clear, though I might be able to create a usable copy.  `matrix` is not a good description of your target, since in `numpy`, `np.matrix` is just a subclass of `ndarray` that must be 2d.  I think you are creating a `factor` or `feature` matrix, something that's used in a package like `scikit-learn`.  I'd suggest editing tags accordingly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is an error in your code, which I corrected with the `sub_data` array line.  I also streamlined the code in some obvious ways:

```
def foo(cov_data):
    factors = np.unique(cov_data['FACTOR_1'])
    no_of_factors = factors.shape[0]
    cov_matrix = np.zeros((no_of_factors, no_of_factors))
    for i,factor_1 in enumerate(factors):
        factor_indices = np.where(cov_data['FACTOR_1'] == factor_1)[0]
        sub_data = cov_data[factor_indices]
        for j,factor_2 in enumerate(factors):
            factor_2_index = np.where(sub_data['FACTOR_2'] == factor_2)[0]
            if factor_2_index.shape[0]==1:
                cov_matrix[i, j] = sub_data['VALUE'][factor_2_index[0]]
            elif factor_2_index.shape[0] ==0:
                pass
            else:
                self.log.error("Found duplicate factor")
    return cov_matrix
```

If I make a structured array from your lists

```
cov_data = np.array([tuple(i) for i in factors], dtype=[('FACTOR_1','|U1'),('FACTOR_2','|U1'),('VALUE','f')])
```

I get this `cov_matrix`:

```
[[ 2.          3.          2.20000005  2.5999999 ]
 [ 2.5999999   1.          6.          7.69999981]
 [ 2.0999999   0.          0.          0.        ]
 [ 0.          0.          0.          2.5999999 ]]
```

I haven't worked with this kind of feature matrix very much, but I think it's the bread-n-butter task in learning code such as `scikit-learn`.

Sometimes the `sklearn` people make sparse matrices.  Here's a simple way of doing that:

```
features1, ind1 = np.unique(cov_data['FACTOR_1'], return_inverse=True)
features2, ind2 = np.unique(cov_data['FACTOR_2'], return_inverse=True)
values = cov_data['VALUE']
from scipy import sparse
M = sparse.coo_matrix((values,(ind1, ind2)))
```

`return_inverse` gives me the index of each unique value in the original array.  So in effect it translates the strings into a row or column index.

The dense version of this matrix `M.A` is the same.

`print(M)` displays the index value triplets:

```
  (0, 0)    2.0
  (0, 1)    3.0
  (0, 2)    2.2
  (0, 3)    2.6
  (1, 0)    2.6
  (1, 1)    1.0
  (1, 2)    6.0
  (1, 3)    7.7
  (2, 0)    2.1
  (3, 3)    2.6
```

There are some rough edges is this calculation, such as how duplicates are handled (values are added), order of the `features` and what to do if one list is not as complete as the other.  `unique` sorts them.

Constructing the dense matrix from the indices is easy too:

```
cov_matrix = np.zeros((len(features1), len(features2)))
cov_matrix[ind1, ind2] = values
print(cov_matrix)
```

(again, it may not handle duplicates right).

Comment: Perfect thank you so much @hpaulj , also some things in Python I didn't realise you could do, it's so damn neat!